# WebParts.aspx page hangs in published site but works when run from VS2008 on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a WebParts.aspx page which looks like this - 
                <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebParts.aspx.cs" Inherits="e.WebParts" %>

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
            <head runat="server">
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <div>

                    <asp:WebPartManager ID="WebPartManager1" runat="server">
                    </asp:WebPartManager>

                </div>

                <div>
                <table>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone1" runat="server" HeaderText="News">
                        <ZoneTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Title="News" ></asp:Label>
                        </ZoneTemplate>
                    </asp:WebPartZone>
                    </td><td>
                        <asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone2" runat="server">
                        </asp:WebPartZone>
                    </td><td>
                        <asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone3" runat="server">
                            <ZoneTemplate>
                                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Title="Sponsors"></asp:ListBox>
                            </ZoneTemplate>
                        </asp:WebPartZone>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                 <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone4" runat="server">
                    </asp:WebPartZone>
                     </td><td>
                         <asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone5" runat="server">
                         </asp:WebPartZone>
                     </td><td>
                         <asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone6" runat="server">
                         </asp:WebPartZone>
                     </td>
                </tr>

                </table>

                </div>
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

This page runs just fine when I run it directly from VS2008 on localhost, but when I publish it to my remote IIS webserver, it just hangs with no HTTP response.

Comment: Your title and the body of your post disagree about which environment it works in and which it hangs in. Please edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your server's firewall.  I've experienced the same behavior using the AJAX Toolkit.